# In Python, how to convert from symbols to emojis?

Tags: python, unicode, symbols, emoji

I have a list of black symbols that I want to show as an emoji. How do I convert from a black symbol to the colorful emoji?

[image]

I was using `import emoji` but that library also uses the black symbols.

```
print('☀')
print('☀️')
```

Comment: Terminals do not have proper colours. You need to "print" where you can select also the font (and select a font with colourful emoji).

Comment: But it's not on the terminal. I am able to print the right emoji on Jupyter Notebook if I copy and paste. What I want to do is to convert the list I have with black symbols into the colorful emojis.

Comment: From what I've read, these characters have different Unicode codes. See https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2600.html and try running `chr(0x2600)` and `chr(0x1F506)`. You will get a black sun and then a colorful sun. Perhaps you can make a mapping between the black emojis and the colorful emojis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the compatibility of your browser/terminal/IDE, a variation selector (U+FE0F) can be used to convert:

```
>>> print('\u2600')
☀
>>> print('\u2600\ufe0f')
☀️
>>> print('\u2708')
✈
>>> print('\u2708\ufe0f')
✈️
```

Comment: and then I solved my problem by adding `\ufe0f` at the end of the black symbols, for example, `print('✈\ufe0f')`. This was exactly it, thank you!